# C# Why does seeding the random generator stop my program?

Tags: c#, random, xna

So I declare a random generator in one of my classes like this

```
static Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

and when calling a function in the class even when that function was blank it appeared to block the entire program from running.

```
static Random random = new Random();
```

But when I do this it worked as expected?

EDIT with code:

This program is specifically an XNA Game so here is the update function

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("This happenens");
    EnemyController.generateEnemies();
    Debug.WriteLine("This does not");
}
```

And here is part of the other class

```
public static class EnemyController
{
    static Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

    public static void generateEnemies()
    {
        Debug.writeLine("This code wont run");
    }
}
```

Comment: Something else is going on. When debugging, what line does your program hang on if you break in mid-execution?

Comment: Not that it's probably relevant here, but is your program multi-threaded? Because `Random` isn't thread-safe...

Comment: Here's an article on how to make `Random` thread-safe: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx

Comment: It will run the line before the call to the function but will not run the first line of the function.

No i'm not using Threads

Comment: How about a *short* block of code that demonstrates the problem? (edited)

Comment: I suppose its because of static. You can get some trouble with static initializers (the order of initialization) if you are not careful. Try to do that without static within a Singleton.

Comment: @BlueM Yes that was actually the answer, when I declared it as a static global variable it blocked, when I declared it inside the function it worked even with the seed. Something to do with called DateTime.Now from within a static maybe?

Comment: This is coding by coincidence at its finest.  For those of us who are actually curious in what was going on, can you post some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @AustinSalonen I've posted some code but it really isn't anything more complex than calling a function from main class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the MSDN documentation for [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) for the parameterless constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent default seed value.

If your instantiation of Random is actually what's blocking your code, then know that you don't need to seed it with the time. However, I would look into other possibilities for your code blocking.